# AutoIT exe works manually but while invoking with JAVA, it just launches cmd and nothing happens after that

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt, autoit

I have an AutoIT script here :

```
;Launch CMD
Run("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
sleep(2000)
$cmdHandle = WinActivate("C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe")
Sleep(2000)

;Sending document
ControlSend($cmdHandle, "", "", "ftp" & @CRLF)
ControlSend($cmdHandle, "", "", "open" & @CRLF)
Sleep(2000)
ControlSend($cmdHandle, "", "", "first command" & @CRLF)
Sleep(2000)
ControlSend($cmdHandle, "", "", "second-coomand" & @CRLF)
```

first-command and second-command I can't provide cause it's internal. I have complied this .au3 file into an exe and it does the work. But I need to invoke this with Java. Java code I have tried is :

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\username\\eclipse-workspace\\Examples\\src\\com\\own\\examples\\etc.exe");
    pb.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Through java it just launches the cmd and nothing happens after that. Please help !!

Comment: Try sending `/c` or `/k` as the first argument. They tend to be required when sending arguments to cmd from non-cmd applications. For example, `ControlSend($cmdHandle, "/c",  "first command" & @CRLF)` then see if it works from java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sending `/c` or the `/k` switches as the first argument in your AutoIt script. This tends to be the requirements when sending arguments to batch-files or cmd related things from non cmd or batch instances. For example, try using:

```
ControlSend($cmdHandle, "/c", "first command" & @CRLF)
```

then see if it works from java.